# Cloud function working locally but crashing in GCP (Function execution took 12681 ms, finished with status: 'crash')

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-logging

Here is a super abbreviated version of my code (I'll put a link to everything in comments)

```py
import ...

...

def main(data, context):
    log_client = logging.Client()

    log_name = 'cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions'

    res = Resource(type="cloud_function",
                   labels={
                       "function_name": "refresh_classes",
                       "region": os.environ.get("FUNC_REGION")
                   })
    logger = log_client.logger(log_name.format(os.environ.get("PROJECT_ID")))

    db = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
        sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL(
            drivername="mysql+pymysql",
            username=os.environ.get("DB_USER"),
            password=os.environ.get("DB_PASS"),
            host=os.environ.get("DB_HOST"),
            port=3306,
            database=PRIMARY_TABLE_NAME
        ),
        pool_size=5,
        max_overflow=2,
        pool_timeout=30,
        pool_recycle=1800
    )
    start_time = perf_counter()

    check_if_table_exists(db)

    for i in range(START_IDX, END_IDX):
        print(i)
        logger.log_text(f"Checking class with id {i}", resource=res, severity="INFO")

        ...

    logger.log_text(f"Total seconds elapsed: {perf_counter() - start_time}", resource=res, severity="INFO")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main('data', 'context')
```

When I run the above cloud function locally, with my `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` configured along with my local Cloud MySQL proxy set up, the verbose cloud logging comes through and the function finishes without a hitch, exactly as I would expect:

[image]

However, when I deploy the entire thing to GCP, and try to trigger it through the console (cloud messaging trigger), all I get is this in terms of logging:

[image]

**actual text**

```
{
 insertId: "******"  
 labels: {
  execution_id: "******"   
 }
 logName: "projects/******/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2020-05-29T22:11:13.435688367Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   function_name: "******"    
   project_id: "******"    
   region: "us-central1"    
  }
  type: "cloud_function"   
 }
 severity: "DEBUG"  
 textPayload: "Function execution started"  
 timestamp: "2020-05-29T22:11:03.069889708Z"  
 trace: "projects/******/traces/******"  
}

{
 insertId: "******"  
 labels: {
  execution_id: "******"   
 }
 logName: "projects/******/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2020-05-29T22:11:16.331311285Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   function_name: "******"    
   project_id: "******"    
   region: "us-central1"    
  }
  type: "cloud_function"   
 }
 severity: "DEBUG"  
 textPayload: "Function execution took 12362 ms, finished with status: 'crash'"  
 timestamp: "2020-05-29T22:11:15.430033249Z"  
 trace: "projects/******/traces/******"  
}
```

*i don't really know what's sensitive information and what's not, so I just starred some random things

As I'm writing this, I realize more logging could help, so I stuck a Google logger in between the logger setup, db setup, and the table check I run.

**The function crashes before the Google logger is even set up.**

So at this point I'm not really sure what could be breaking my function, and I don't know how to find out, seeing as Google Cloud logging is of no help. The error json has a `trace` property which looks really promising, because all I need at this point is a Python stack trace, but I don't know if there's a way to see that.

I should note that I have environment variables configured through GCP's Cloud Function console.

[image]

Principally, there are two things that would be helpful:

1. how to see python stack trace of crashing cloud function
2. what, specific to my application, could be causing it to exhibit this crashing behavior

Comment: Can you share your requirement.txt file and how do you deploy the fonction? (without sensitive information)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally figured out that if, instead of triggering your cloud function via Cloud Scheduler, you run the function manually via `Test Function`

[image]

GCP will give you the raised exception. In my case, my Cloud MySQL connection was failing

```
Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Details:
(pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '**.***.**.***' (timed out)")
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

so I simply had to introduce an environment variable to toggle between connecting via proxy and [unix sockets](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-functions#public-ip-default_1) like such:

```py
if os.environ.get("ENV") == "local":
    db = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
        sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL(
            drivername="mysql+pymysql",
            username=os.environ.get("DB_USER"),
            password=os.environ.get("DB_PASS"),
            host=os.environ.get("DB_HOST"),
            port=3306,
            database=PRIMARY_TABLE_NAME
        ),
        pool_size=5,
        max_overflow=2,
        pool_timeout=30,
        pool_recycle=1800
    )
else:
    db = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
        sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL(
            drivername="mysql+pymysql",
            username=os.environ.get("DB_USER"),
            password=os.environ.get("DB_PASS"),
            database=PRIMARY_TABLE_NAME,
            query={"unix_socket": "/cloudsql/{}".format(os.environ.get("CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME"))}
        ),
        pool_size=5,
        max_overflow=2,
        pool_timeout=30,
        pool_recycle=1800
    )
```